# Trying to determine if mouse clicked inside window region

Tags: autohotkey

I have a simple Autohotkey script that I want to use to determine if the mouse was clicked inside a window.  I want the function to fail if the click was on the title bar or on the scroll bars of the window.  My script looks like this:

```
LButton::  
WinGetPos, X, Y, Width, Height, A  
MouseGetPos, x,y  
Rightmargin := Width - 50  
Topmargin := Y+25  


if (x < Rightmargin and y > Topmargin)  


   MsgBox You're Inside  

return
```

The problem is when I run this, it freezes up my machine.  All the left mouse clicks are captured and do not get through to the system and for some reason the test case always fails (I never see the MsgBox).

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you should get rid of all `%`'s in your `if`-statement. Plus, it is impossible to understand your code as it is now

Comment: try editing your startpost instead.. there is special higlighting for code snippets. 4 Spaces in front of a line will format it.

Comment: If I add the following line:  
 
    "MouseClick, left"  

    then mouse clicks go through, but the if statement is still failing

Comment: I figured out the problem.  I was overwriting the x and y values with MouseGetPos.  I needed to calculate the margins before MouseGetPos.  After I made this change, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Variables, Labelnames and so on are case-insensitive in AutoHotkey. So, with `WinGetPos, X, Y` and `MouseGetPos, x,y`, you are allocating these two variables twice, overwriting the window's position coordinates. So, for example, you might want to rename `x` to `mouseX` and `y` to `mouseY`.

Since you obviously want your mouse coordinates being measured by the current window, you should also include `coordmode, mouse, relative` before your hotkey assignments.

Finally, if you also want your Click to be send to the window, includ a tilde `~` before your Hotkey: `~LButton::`.